# Flutter Grid auto scroll doesn't work accordingly

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app I have in a Scaffold a Grid Controller which display generated tiles(cards) with 4 columns and max 50 rows. Also I have a button, which generate a new tile and append it to a grid.

Basically my app works like this: It starts with an empty grid, and if you press on the button it will generate and add a new a tile till max 50 pieces.
Now, my grid dimension is 4x5 , which means I'm able to display max 20 tiles with no scroll, and already starting from 21 I should scroll it down to see new tiles.

I want to implement a logic in order to do autoscroll when the number of tiles is > than 20.

I've tried to use a Scroll Controller, but it works in a strange way: if I add the tile number 21 (basically row number 6) then the scroll controller will not be called, but for tiles 22,23,24 - it will be.

My code looks like this :

```
ScrollController _scrollController;
...
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); 

   // Scoll Controler
   _scrollController = new ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0, keepScrollOffset: true );
}
... 

  void _toEnd() {                                                      
      _scrollController.animateTo(                                     
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, 
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),                    
      curve: Curves.ease,
    ); 
  }           
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ... 
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton (
                onPressed: () {
                     // append new tile to grid 
                     setState(() { actual_cards = actual_cards + 1; });
                    _toEnd();
                  };
  }
```

I checked and it seems that my problem is with `_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent`, because when I add tile 21 it still has value 0.0 , and on 22 it has value 61.71.

How can I trigger this parameter update when I press my button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this code in Widget build :

```
// After 1 ,milisecond, it takes you to the bottom of the Grid View
Timer( Duration( milliseconds: 1), () =>  _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.ease,),
);
```